# Convert 32 bit binary to a decimal in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, decimal

how do I convert Convert 32 bit binary to a decimal in python

this

```
00011110001101110110110000001000
```

to

506948616

this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use in-built function int():

```
a = '00011110001101110110110000001000'
a_dec = int(a, 2)
```

Comment: This works great for positive numbers but not for negative ones where the leading digit is `1`.  You need additional work for that.

Answer (score 1):

use `int` for conversion of a string (just give the correct base as parameter):

```
int('00011110001101110110110000001000', 2)
```

Another way is to add `0b` as a prefix for the number (same as `0x` for hex values or `0o` for octal values):

```
x=0b00011110001101110110110000001000
```

`x` will be an integer with decimal value of `506948616`